# what is the default on delete and on update

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is MySQL's default ON DELETE behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027656/what-is-mysqls-default-on-delete-behavior)

Hi all just want to know what the on delete and on update are set to on a foreign key if you dont specify what they are on a MYSQL database.  I've been searching and cant really find out the answer.  Like if I just create a foreign key what are they set too.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is MySQL's default ON DELETE behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027656/what-is-mysqls-default-on-delete-behavior) (via a.stgeorge)

Comment: @BoltClock I came across the question and I couldn't get the answer to the question "what is the default on delete and on update?". I got the answer from here. The only thing I feel this question will useful to users than the original question. A normal computer programmers feel the SO is only for brilliant programmers if moderators keep Closing this type of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the default action is RESTRICT.

via http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: It appears that with MySQL 8.x, the default action has changed to NO ACTION
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the MySQL docs:

```
If ON DELETE or ON UPDATE are not specified, the default action is RESTRICT.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

The default is to disallow any update or delete of a parent row if it would orphan one or more child rows.

In this case the error looks like this:

```
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```