# Default behavior in mysql on delete

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

If I do this

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_table` 
FOREIGN KEY (`IDtable`) 
REFERENCES `table2` (`ID`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

What is default behavior for ON DELETE? Is it restrict, cascade, set null?

Comment: `NO ACTION`

Related; [What is MySQL's default ON DELETE behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027656/what-is-mysqls-default-on-delete-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set an action, the default will be `NO ACTION`.

Comment: Which is the same as `RESTRICT`.

Comment: `RESTRICT` and `NO ACTION` are ***not*** the same in the SQL standard, but *are* the same in MySQL.