# Default value of ondelete attibute of addForeignKeyConstraint liquibase

Tags: sql, liquibase

According to this documentation:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_foreign_key_constraint.html

liquibase allows to create foreign keys. There is an interesting attribute there called *onDelete*. It is written that possible values are: 'CASCADE', 'SET NULL', 'SET DEFAULT', 'RESTRICT', 'NO ACTION', but it is not explicitly mentioned which one is *default* one.

Any ideas? Or is it better just to mention it explicitly?

I guess that it can depend on the database as well. I use PostgreSQL, MySQL and MsSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify a value, Liquibase will not include any additional clauses in the SQL so it actually depends on your database default.

The default behavior is normally RESTRICT.

Comment: I was actually thinking that it is 'NO ACTION', but according to this post these values are almost the same: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027656/what-is-mysqls-default-on-delete-behavior

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Update**

Here is the [list](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-foreign-key-constraint.html) of supported databases for `onDelete` attribute of Liquibase till the latest [version](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases) `(4.*.*)`, as [Voxland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45756/nathan-voxland) mentioned it depends to database behavior for onDelte cascading, but mostly is **No Action**, here i attached some of famous supported ones.

- [Postgress](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) (**No Action**)
- [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_int.htm#CNCPT1629) (**No Action**)
- [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17629936/15758781) (**No Action**)
- [MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186712.aspx) (**No Action**)