# Difference between MySQL's on update / delete "NO ACTION" vs blank

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've read this question:
[What is MySQL's default ON DELETE behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027656/what-is-mysqls-default-on-delete-behavior) which outlines the behaviours of different options - NO ACTION, RESTRICT, SET NULL, and CASCADE for on update / on delete actions for MySQL foreign keys.

However, there's another option - just blank. You can set it to blank - it's not a required field per se.

What does leaving it blank do? Is it the same as setting it to "NO ACTION"?

[image: picture]

Comment: This seems more a question about phpmyadmin than mysql itself. I don't use it, but my guess is it's equivalent to not having an ON DELETE option in the CREATE TABLE command.

Comment: It's not a question about phpmyadmin - I don't use that either. That screenshot is from Navicat, and the option is also available in Sequel Pro.

Comment: Fair enough, but my point is that the meaning of a menu option depends on that GUI application, not the RDBMS itself. I was only wrong about which GUI application you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for InnoDB's foreign key handling is not clear about this.  I would also speculate that the default action depends on the engine.

Most likely you are using InnoDB.

Based on my own testing, not specifying the `ON` action for a foreign key is the same as `NO ACTION`, which for InnoDB is also the same as `RESTRICT`.  It does change output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` though.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I'm using InnoDB