# Cannot delete or update a parent row: spring problem without cascade

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hrms`.`employees`, CONSTRAINT `FKe4i9i8vu1j96m71g4v98kqirb` FOREIGN KEY (`designation_id`) REFERENCES `designations` (`id`))

I just land on this problem, I try to delete an entity, but the entity have a relation with another entity and another entity have another relation to imagine the picture this is the tables [image]

How to detach employee and designation from department when I want to delete department. I can delete designations in the code, but I don't want to delete the employee with foreign key associated to the department and designation.

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
    `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `designations` (
    `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `department_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `employees` (
    `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `dob` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    `employee_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `join_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `phone_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `department_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    `designation_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    `avatar_image` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FKgy4qe3dnqrm3ktd76sxp7n4c2` (`department_id`),
    KEY `FKe4i9i8vu1j96m71g4v98kqirb` (`designation_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FKe4i9i8vu1j96m71g4v98kqirb` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`designation_id`) 
        REFERENCES `designations` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FKgy4qe3dnqrm3ktd76sxp7n4c2` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) 
        REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Its would be better to show us a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each relevant, related table. Then we can see what has been done and what has been missed.

Comment: I updated it. I need a way to detach the employee from department and designation .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027656/what-is-mysqls-default-on-delete-behavior Look at the accepted answer on that question

Comment: Thank you for the link, I check it, but I can't see an example for spring

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can quite understand what they mean in this question What I need to do to make another table witch will hold relation for department and designation as departmen_designation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is completely irrelevant to your question. Its all about the MySQL database and the way you have defined the tables in your DDL.

You cannot delete a Parent row if a Child row exists on your database because of how you defined that constraint.

There is a `ON DELETE ....` syntax which tells MySQL what to do when a parent row is deleted, by default MySQL will reject the delete, you can change this in a number of ways, as specified in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), of all the odd places.

In your case as you want to NOT DELETE the Employee when you delete the Department, and you have the column

```
`department_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
```

defined as DEFAULT NULL then change your CONSTRAINT as below

```
CONSTRAINT `FKgy4qe3dnqrm3ktd76sxp7n4c2` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) 
        REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
```

You could of course also do

```
CONSTRAINT `FKgy4qe3dnqrm3ktd76sxp7n4c2` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) 
        REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
    ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
```

both would do the same thing in this case as your default is NULL for that column