# View all foreign key constraints for entire MySQL database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database

I have a large database with over 150 tables that I've recently been handed.  I'm just wondering if there is an easy way to view all foreign key constraints for the entire DB instead of on a per-table basis.

Comment: See Andy's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html) tables for this. For example, the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) table.

Something like this should do it:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Comment: Looks like that has exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to actually list the field name of the foreign key too?

Answer (score 26):

This is what I prefer to get useful informations:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
       MATCH_OPTION, 
       UPDATE_RULE,
       DELETE_RULE,
       TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
```

Answer (score 7):

The currently accepted answer by user RedFilter will work fine if you have just 1 database, but not if you have many.

After entering `use information_schema;` use this query to get foreign keys for `name_of_db`:

```
select * from `table_constraints` where `table_schema` like `name_of_db` and `constraint_type` = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Use this query to get foreign keys for `name_of_db` saved to world-writeable file `output_filepath_and_name`:

```
select * from `table_constraints` where `table_schema` like "name_of_db" and `constraint_type` = 'FOREIGN KEY' into outfile "output_filepath_and_name" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Answer (score 2):

Query this code

```
select constraint_name,
   table_schema,
   table_name
from   information_schema.table_constraints
```

You will get constraint_name, and filter the table_schema which is the list of `database`.

[Look at This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bbf7a/1)

Answer (score 1):

**SQL:**

```
select constraint_name,
       table_schema,
       table_name
from   information_schema.table_constraints
where  constraint_schema = 'astdb'
```

**Output:**

```
+----------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| constraint_name            | table_schema | table_name          |
+----------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | asset_category      |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | asset_type          |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | asset_valuation     |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | assets              |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | com_mst             |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | com_typ             |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | ref_company_type    |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | supplier            |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | third_party_company |
| third_party_company_ibfk_1 | astdb        | third_party_company |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | user                |
| PRIMARY                    | astdb        | user_role           |
+----------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RefCons.constraint_schema, RefCons.table_name, RefCons.referenced_table_name, RefCons.constraint_name, KeyCol.column_name, KeyCol.referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints RefCons
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage KeyCol ON RefCons.constraint_schema = KeyCol.table_schema
     AND RefCons.table_name = KeyCol.table_name
     AND RefCons.constraint_name = KeyCol.constraint_name
WHERE RefCons.constraint_schema = 'DATABASE_NAME';
```