# Show constraints on tables command

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have tables that I've tried setting PK FK relationships on but I want to verify this. How can I show the PK/FK restraints? I saw [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-constraints-table.html) manual page, but it does not show examples and my google search was fruitless also. My database is `credentialing1` and my constrained tables are `practices` and `cred_insurances`.

Answer (score 500):

I use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

This shows you the SQL statement necessary to receate `mytable` in its current form. You can see all the columns and their types (like `DESC`) but it also shows you constraint information (and table type, charset, etc.).

Comment: i don't think it shows the incoming fk relations? as in for example, `a.col_one references b.col_one` and in `show create table b` will not contain detail about the aforementioned relation.

Comment: I confirmed that this command does not display the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Beware that MariaDB starting with 10.2 will return awkward results here. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15377

Comment: I believe this wont show constrains further than PK

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!!! It's simple and gives an amazing and detailed output!!! I use mysql **Ver 8.0.23 for Win64** and I get FK information:

```CONSTRAINT `t_incomes_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`f_production_id`) REFERENCES `t_productions` (`m_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `t_incomes_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`f_field_id`) REFERENCES `t_fields` (`m_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE```

Answer (score 143):

Simply query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "<your_database_name>" 
      AND TABLE_NAME = "<your_table_name>" 
      AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it gives you the result in a format that you can use programmatically. Of course you will need to add a WHERE clause to narrow down the results

Comment: This helped me find a corrupt table that had  the column 'id' referencing several foreign keys.  No wonder the table got 1452 IntegrityError.

Comment: I love that you prefixed your answer with "Simply." Great answer, though!

Comment: That will not display actual constraint rules - e.g. `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: The only disadvantage of the above is, key_column_usage will only show keys that are in use. So for empty tables you won't get any results.

Answer (score 24):

afaik to make a request to `information_schema` you need privileges. If you need simple list of keys you can use this command:

```
SHOW INDEXES IN <tablename>
```

Comment: How is calling information_schema is better than this, thanks alot

Answer (score 22):

The main problem with the validated answer is you'll have to parse the output to get the informations. Here is a query allowing you to get them in a more usable manner :

```
SELECT cols.TABLE_NAME, cols.COLUMN_NAME, cols.ORDINAL_POSITION,
cols.COLUMN_DEFAULT, cols.IS_NULLABLE, cols.DATA_TYPE,
    cols.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,
    cols.NUMERIC_PRECISION, cols.NUMERIC_SCALE,
    cols.COLUMN_TYPE, cols.COLUMN_KEY, cols.EXTRA,
    cols.COLUMN_COMMENT, refs.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, refs.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
    cRefs.UPDATE_RULE, cRefs.DELETE_RULE,
    links.TABLE_NAME, links.COLUMN_NAME,
    cLinks.UPDATE_RULE, cLinks.DELETE_RULE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` as cols
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS refs
ON refs.TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND refs.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND refs.TABLE_NAME=cols.TABLE_NAME
    AND refs.COLUMN_NAME=cols.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS cRefs
ON cRefs.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND cRefs.CONSTRAINT_NAME=refs.CONSTRAINT_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS links
ON links.TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND links.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND links.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME=cols.TABLE_NAME
    AND links.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME=cols.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS cLinks
ON cLinks.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=cols.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND cLinks.CONSTRAINT_NAME=links.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE cols.TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
    AND cols.TABLE_NAME="table"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
select
    table_name,column_name,referenced_table_name,referenced_column_name
from
    information_schema.key_column_usage
where
    referenced_table_name is not null
    and table_schema = 'my_database' 
    and table_name = 'my_table'
```

Or for better formatted output use this:

```
select
    concat(table_name, '.', column_name) as 'foreign key',  
    concat(referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name) as 'references'
from
    information_schema.key_column_usage
where
    referenced_table_name is not null
    and table_schema = 'my_database' 
    and table_name = 'my_table'
```

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 5 

Line 29 is "information_schema.key_column_usage"

Comment: @noboundaries you're trying that on Oracle, the question is about MySQL

Answer (score 6):

Try doing:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM credentialing1;
```

The foreign key constraints are listed in the *Comment* column of the output.

Comment: I see only table comments in the Comment column. It is probably something to do with InnoDB types.

Comment: Comments are only for user comments. That's for sure not the place where FK definitions are stored! If they're for you - it must have been done on your behalf by some RDBMS tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a tool that oracle made called [mysqlshow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlshow.html)

If you run it with the `--k keys $table_name` option it will display the keys.

```
SYNOPSIS
   mysqlshow [options] [db_name [tbl_name [col_name]]]
.......
.......
.......
·   --keys, -k
   Show table indexes.
```

example:

```
╰─➤  mysqlshow -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p --keys database tokens
Database: database  Table: tokens
+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field           | Type             | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned |                    | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| token           | text             | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| user_id         | int(10) unsigned |                    | NO   | MUL |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| expires_in      | datetime         |                    | YES  |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| created_at      | timestamp        |                    | YES  |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| updated_at      | timestamp        |                    | YES  |     |         |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
+--------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tokens | 0          | PRIMARY                  | 1            | id          | A         | 2           |          |        |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tokens | 1          | tokens_user_id_foreign   | 1            | user_id     | A         | 2           |          |        |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Analogous to [@Resh32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12095312/4217744), but without the need to use the `USE` statement:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "database_name" 
      AND TABLE_NAME = "table_name" 
      AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Useful, e.g. using the ORM.

Comment: That will not display actual constraint rules - e.g. `ON UPDATE CASCADE`