# MySQL Foreign Key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

I've created several tables, one being the parent table and three children tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
 `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`memberID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `pets` (
 `petsID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Gender` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Age` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Size` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`petsID`),
 KEY `fk_pets` (`memberID`),
 CONSTRAINT `pets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`memberID`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `owner` (
 `ownerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nameOwner` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `ageOwner` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `bioOwner` varchar(800) NOT NULL,
 `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ownerID`),
 KEY `fk_owner` (`memberID`),
 CONSTRAINT `owner_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`memberID`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `service` (
 `serviceID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nameService` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `webService` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`serviceID`),
 KEY `fk_service` (`memberID`),
 CONSTRAINT `service_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`memberID`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

After testing out my table I've gotten this error:

```
INSERT INTO owner (nameOwner, ageOwner, bioOwner) VALUES ('', '', '')
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB`.`owner`, CONSTRAINT `owner_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`memberID`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I've already tried truncating my parent table but it still comes up with this error. I'm a beginner at database design so please explain like I'm 5.

Comment: OK - like you're five: you're trying to insert a row in a child row that has no parent it can refer to.

Comment: @HoboSapiens There is something very wrong with "OK - like you're five..."

Comment: @Ajoy - I am merely obliging the OP in his own request. Read his last sentence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005388/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: @HoboSapiens Ah! My mistake. I only read the code. Didn't see the last part. Apologies!

Answer (score 3):

```
CONSTRAINT `owner_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`memberID`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberID`)
```

This constraint on the owner table means that every row in that table needs to have a valid `memberID`. It is only considered *valid* if it exists in the `memberID` column of the `members` table.

Your `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO owner (nameOwner, ageOwner, bioOwner) VALUES ('', '', '')
```

does not *provide* a `memberID` to be inserted so whatever is being used<sup>1</sup> is obviously not in the `members` table. Hence the constraint violation.

Easiest fix is to provide a valid `memberID` in your `insert` statement, one that already exists in `members`.

By way of an example, this would work, assuming you don't yet have a `42` in `members`:

```
insert into members (memberID, username, password) values (
    42,
    'paxdiablo',
    'never_you_mind');
insert into owner (nameOwner, ageOwner, bioOwner, memberID) values (
    'Pax Diablo',
    'too damn old',
    'no idea what this should be',
    42);
```

If you don't *know* what the member ID should be, you can use something like:

```
insert into owner (nameOwner, ageOwner, bioOwner, memberID) 
    select 'Pax Diablo',
           'too damn old',
           'no idea what this should be',
           memberID
      from members where username = 'paxdiablo';
```

though you'd probably want `members.memberID` to be unique.

---

<sup>1</sup> What actually happens here depends on the version of MySQL you're using and whether it's running in strict SQL mode or not. I *think,* from memory, it will either fail the `insert` or use zero as the default.

Comment: So then I have to edit my insert statement to INSERT INTO owner (nameOwner, ageOwner, bioOwner,memberID) VALUES ('xx', 'xx', 'xx','') ? Would I keep its VALUE empty like presented above? Thanks for your help btw, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @laimingl, that'll only work if you have a member id of `''` in the `members` table, and it will link all inserts to that row. That's unlikely to be what you want. Instead, you need to find the correct record in `members` and insert its `memberID` into `owner` with the other data.