# Foreign key constraint not being implemented

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a foreign key between the following two tables:

> student:
>
> id (PK, Not null, unique, AI)
>
> student_number (Not null, unique)
>
> ... (other columns with no constrains)

and

> project:
>
> id (pk, not null, unique, AI)
>
> student_number(not null)
>
> ... (other columns with no constrains)

The syntax I am using is :

```
ALTER table project 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_project_student FOREIGN KEY (student_number) 
REFERENCES student (student_number) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

However I get the following:

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

*In case you ask, there are no team projects, so it is a simple one -to - many relationship.*

Comment: This would suggest that you already have data in the table that is not compatible with the foreign key constraint.

Comment: you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005388/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have records that do not meet the foreign key constraint. Find them by using

```
SELECT project.student_id from project 
LEFT JOIN student ON project.student_number = student.student_number
WHERE student.student_number IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the way to figure out the problem. Some records from table project referenced non-existent values of the table student. The database was not mine to begin with and had a huge amount of rows. It never occurred to me that there would be records from the child table without a parent record because the data were exported from another database with functioning foreign keys.

Comment: Glad to have helped