# Codeigniter|: error inserting image into mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

Everytime I insert an image to database i got this error

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`herbalcebu`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`categorie_id`) REFERENCES `categorie` (`categorie_id`))
>
> INSERT INTO `product` (`product_image`) VALUES ('q3.jpg')
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/HerbalCebu/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

This is my Controller Code

```
public function insert_product()
{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name','Productname','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price','Amount','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_stock','Stock','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categorie_id','categorie_id','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_description','Description','required');
     $config = array
        (
            'upload_path' => './assets/img',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg|bmp',
            'max_size'=> 0,
            'filename' => $_FILES['product_image']['name']
    );
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))
    {
        $uploaddata  = $this->upload->data();
        $product_image=$uploaddata['file_name'];
        $this->db->insert('product',array('product_image'=>$this->upload->file_name));
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        unset($data['submit']);
        $this->load->model('queries_product');  
        if($this->queries_product->insert_product($data))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Successfully Inserted');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Insert');
        }
        return redirect('inventory');
    }
    else
    {
        echo validation_errors ();
    }
}
```

My Model Code

```
public function insert_product($data)
    {   
        return $this->db->insert('product',$data);

    }
```

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5005457/2275490

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005388/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing an image insertion if image is uploaded, then do a whole data insert if form is validated.

Your product table have a `categorie_id` field constraint, that cannot be empty & should be exist on the categorie table, so you got the error above.

You should merge the `product_image` data with the whole product data by adding conditional if uploaded add additional uploaded image data :

```
public function insert_product()
{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name','Productname','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price','Amount','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_stock','Stock','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categorie_id','categorie_id','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_description','Description','required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
        {
               $data = $this->input->post();
               $config = array
                (
                'upload_path' => './assets/img',
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg|bmp',
                'max_size'=> 0,
                'filename' => $_FILES['product_image']['name']
                 );
                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))
                {
                    $uploaddata  = $this->upload->data();
                    $product_image=$uploaddata['file_name'];
                    $data['product_image'] = $product_image;
                 } 
                unset($data['submit']);
                $this->load->model('queries_product');  
                if($this->queries_product->insert_product($data))
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Successfully Inserted');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Insert');
                 }
                 return redirect('inventory');
         }
        else
        {
                echo validation_errors ();
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your categoryID does not match a category