# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails, but the foreign value is there?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have scene a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005388/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) on this error, but my problem is that I get this error while the foreign key value is clearly in the **Contact Table**

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`client_schedule`.`appointments`, CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Contact_ID`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`Contact_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:354)
    at com.example.customerdatabaseprojectii/com.example.customerdatabaseprojectii.daos.AppointmentsDao.updateAppointment(AppointmentsDao.java:61)
    at com.example.customerdatabaseprojectii/com.example.customerdatabaseprojectii.view.AppointmentFormController.addAppointmentClicked(AppointmentFormController.java:241)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The error gets thrown from this method:

```java
private static final String appointmentUpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointments SET Appointment_ID = ?, Title = ?, Description = ?, " +
        "Location = ?, Type = ?, Start = ?, End = ?, Last_Update = ?, Last_Updated_By = ?, " +
        "Customer_ID = ?, User_ID = ?, Contact_ID = ? WHERE Appointment_ID = ?";

public static void updateAppointment(Appointments appointment) throws SQLException {
    Connection apptConnection = DbConnection.getConnection();
    DbConnection.makePreparedStatement(appointmentUpdateQuery, apptConnection);
    PreparedStatement ps = DbConnection.getPreparedStatement();
    if (ps != null) {
        ps.setInt(1, appointment.getAppointmentID());
        ps.setString(2, appointment.getTitle());
        ps.setString(3, appointment.getDescription());
        ps.setString(4, appointment.getLocation());
        ps.setString(5, appointment.getType());
        ps.setTimestamp(6, Timestamp.valueOf(appointment.getStartDateTime()));
        ps.setTimestamp(7, Timestamp.valueOf(appointment.getEndDateTime()));
        ps.setTimestamp(8, Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        ps.setString(9, UsersDao.getUserNameByID(appointment.getUsersID()));
        ps.setInt(10, appointment.getCustomerID());
        ps.setInt(11, appointment.getUsersID());
        ps.setInt(12, appointment.getContactsID());
        ps.setInt(13, appointment.getAppointmentID());
        
        if(ps.execute()) {
            AppointmentFormController.isValidated = true;
        }
```

Here is the calling method:

```java
public void addAppointmentClicked(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
  Appointments scheduleAppointment = new Appointments();
  fieldValidator(scheduleAppointment);
  DateTimeFormatter hourAndMinuteFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
  try {
    LocalDate localAppointmentDate = afDatePicker.getValue();
    LocalTime localEndTime = RelatedTime.formattedTimeParser(hourAndMinuteFormat, afEndTimePicker.getValue());
    LocalTime localStartTime = RelatedTime.formattedTimeParser(hourAndMinuteFormat, afStartTimePicker.getValue());
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeStartAppointment = LocalDateTime.of(localAppointmentDate, localStartTime);
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeEndAppointment = LocalDateTime.of(localAppointmentDate, localEndTime);
    scheduleAppointment.setStartDateTime(localDateTimeStartAppointment);
    scheduleAppointment.setEndDateTime(localDateTimeEndAppointment);
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("Date or time selection is null");
  }
  try {
    if (!isModified && fieldValidator() && compareAppointmentToBusiness(scheduleAppointment)) {
      insertAppointmentIntoMap(scheduleAppointment.getAppointmentID(), scheduleAppointment); //is validated set false if sql exception caught
      AppointmentsDao.insertAppointmentIntoDB(scheduleAppointment); //WHERE ERROR IS OCCURRING
      isModified = false;
      if (isValidated) {
        closeSceneWindow();
      }
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("There was an error inserting the appointment into the database");
  }
  try {
    if (isModified && fieldValidator() && compareAppointmentToBusiness(scheduleAppointment)) {
      insertAppointmentIntoMap(scheduleAppointment.getAppointmentID(), scheduleAppointment);
      AppointmentsDao.updateAppointment(scheduleAppointment);
      isModified = false;
      if (isValidated) {
        closeSceneWindow();
      }
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

[image: Database Design]
**Contact Table**

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`client_schedule`.`appointments`, CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Contact_ID`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`Contact_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
```

[image: Database table]

I have tried to do first check that all the entered text fields that pertain to foreign keys are found within the database before executing the query.

```java
if (UsersDao.getAllUsersObservableList().stream().
        anyMatch(m -> Objects.equals(m.getUser_ID(), appointment.getUsersID())) &&
        CustomerMainController.getAllCustomers().stream().
                anyMatch(m -> Objects.equals(m.getCustomerID(), appointment.getCustomerID())) &&
        ContactsDao.addContactToObservableList().stream().
                anyMatch(m -> Objects.equals(m.getContactID(), appointment.getContactsID()))) {
    if (ps.execute()) {
        System.out.println("Successfully inserted appointment into database" +
                "\nTime: " + LocalTime.now());
        AppointmentFormController.isValidated = true;
    }
} else {
    AppointmentFormController.isValidated = false;
}
```

But when I did this I got this error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'appointments.PRIMARY'
```

After I got this error I tried to remove `SET Appointment_ID = ?` from the query and also the prepared statement. I am pretty confused with whether its my query that is the issue or what is being checked that goes in it.

Comment: *a foreign key constraint fails, but the foreign value is there?* If constraint fails then the value is not present. No variants. "Value is present' and "you think that it is present" is not the same. Enable General Log and look the queries which are received by MySQL really.

Comment: Check value of `appointment.getCustomerID()` if it contains a valid Customer‘s ID

Comment: @ChristophDahlen it is the `appointment.getContactsID()` the OP needs to check, not the customer one :)

Comment: @Shadow You are correct.