# Why not have a JOINONE keyword in SQL to hint and enforce that each record has at most one match?

Tags: sql

I encounter this a lot when writing SQL. I have two tables that are meant to be in a one-to-one relationship with each other, and I wish I could easily assert that fact in my query. For example, the simplified query:

```
SELECT Person.ID, Person.Name, Location.Address1
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN Location ON Person.LocationID = Location.ID
```

When I read this query I think to myself, well what if the Location table fails to enforce uniqueness on its ID column? Suddenly you could have the same Person multiple times in your resultset. Sure, I can go look at the schema to assure myself it's unique so everything will be okay, but why shouldn't I simply be able to put it right here in my query, a la:

```
SELECT Person.ID, Person.Name, Location.Address1
FROM Person
LEFT JOINONE Location ON Person.LocationID = Location.ID
```

Not only would a keyword like this (made up "JOINONE") make it 100% clear to a human reading this query that we are guaranteed to get exactly one row for each Person record, but it lets the db engine optimize its execution plan because it knows there won't be more than one match each, even if the foreign key relationship isn't defined in the schema.

Another advantage of this would be that the db engine could enforce it, so if the data actually did have more than one match, an error could be thrown. This happens for subqueries already, e.g.:

```
SELECT Person.ID, Person.Name
 , (
    SELECT Location.Address1 
    FROM Location 
    WHERE Location.ID = Person.Location
   ) AS Address1
FROM Person
```

This is nice and spiffy, 100% clear to the human reader, neatly optimizable, and enforced by the db engine. In fact I often end up doing things this way for all those reasons. The problem is, besides the distracting syntax, you can only select one field this way. (What if I want City, State, and Zip too?) How nice it would be if you could flow this table right along with the rest of your JOINs and select any fields from it you wish in your SELECT clause just like all the rest of your tables.

I couldn't find any other question like this around StackOverflow, though I did find lots of repeats of a close question: people wanting to *choose* a single record. Close but really quite a different kind of goal, and less meaningful in my opinion.

I'm posting this question to see if there's some mechanism already in the SQL language that I'm missing, or an efficient workaround anyone has come up with. The concept of a one-to-one vs. one-to-many relationship is so fundamental to relational database design, I'm just so surprised at the absence of this language element.

Comment: Most of SQL operates on set (colletion-of-something) math, so the concept of "1 row" isn't completely relevant; either the set is empty, or it has contents.  It gets trickier when you consider that most optimizers are free to reorder joins, which might mean you get multiple rows temporarily, before they're pruned from the rest of the joins/`WHERE` clause.  Subqueries are something of a different context (especially because you can use them with `=`), but note that address is often something there may be multiple of legitimately...

Comment: Isn't this what a unique constraint is for?

Comment: I think that foreign keys are what you're talking about.

Comment: Sure, say there can't be a constraint because there might be multiple Location records for some other referencing table (say, Business) but for a query that deals with Person it's entirely appropriate (in my imaginary domain) to enforce a single lookup.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is two languages in one. Constraints, including uniqueness constraints, are set using the data definition language (DDL) in SQL. This is a layer above the data manipulation language (DML), where SELECT statements live, and it's understood that statements issued in the DDL might invalidate statements in the DML.

There's no way for a query to prevent someone from executing an ALTER TABLE command and changing the name of a field that the query refers to between query runs.

And there isn't much more of a way for a query to be written defensively against uncertain constraints; it's OK if you need to ask someone for information outside of the database environment to address this. The information may also be available within the environment; in most engines, you get to it by querying the data dictionary. This is the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12095312/881615), for instance.

Comment: It's because of this separate but interactive marriage between DML and DDL that I wish the former had this mechanism. In a query I'm allowed to choose an inner join rather than left join, or to join on fields/rules that are not defined in the schema; why not also be able to assert a one-to-one relationship that's special to the context of the query? I might not be asserting anything about the schema at all, just something about the data sets in question.