# How do I identify all foreign key references to a primary key throughout an entire database?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

My question is about foreign keys. For example, we have table X with X_PK and tables A, B, C with null A_FK_X and null B_FK_X. Table C doesn't contain an FK to table X. Table A already had records with A_FK_X initialised, but table B doesn't.

Is it possible to find all usages of specified X_PK in all tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `information_schema` database. Try this code (albeit with oversimplified `CREATE TABLE` statements):

```
CREATE TABLE `X` (
    `X_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`X_id`)
  );

  CREATE TABLE `A` (
    `A_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `X_id` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`A_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `A_FK_X` FOREIGN KEY (`X_id`) REFERENCES `X` (`X_id`)
  );

CREATE TABLE `B` (
    `B_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `X_id` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`B_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `B_FK_X` FOREIGN KEY (`X_id`) REFERENCES `X` (`X_id`)
  );

CREATE TABLE `C` (
  `C_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`C_id`)
);

USE information_schema;
SELECT * FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'X_id';
```

This will return all references to `X_id` in every database, so you could narrow your search by including a `TABLE_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT * FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'X_id' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='testdbname';
```

On my system, these return the same output, since I only have one database that includes references to `X_id`, but the output will vary depending on your database/table structure.

Comment: Great! But what if, for example, we have X_PK = 5. And in table A we have two records with A_FK_X = 5, and table B doesn't contains similar records. Is it possible to find that 2 records from table A? Or just define number of similar records across whole db?

Comment: You *could* use a stored procedure with prepared statements to achieve that, but I would strongly suggest 1) fetching the resultant rows using the above query, 2) iterating through them in your front-end to fetch the table and column names, then 3) building queries with those table and column names and the relevant `WHERE` clause. That code depends on your front-end, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can go for following query:

select constraint_schema,constraint_name,table_name,column_name,referenced_table_name,referenced_column_name 
from `information_schema.key_column_usage`