# Update SQL with Where AND Where Conditions in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

This is my code:

```
public function remove_employee( $emp_no, $now ) {
    $this->db->delete('employees', array('emp_no' => $emp_no));
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    $this->db->start_cache();
    $this->db->where('emp_no', $emp_no);
    $this->db->where('to_date', '9999-01-01');
    $this->db->update('dept_emp', array('to_date' => $now));
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $this->db->flush_cache();   

    $this->db->start_cache();
    $this->db->where('emp_no', $emp_no);
    $this->db->where('to_date', '9999-01-01');
    $this->db->update('salaries', array('to_date' => $now));
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $this->db->flush_cache();   

    $this->db->start_cache();
    $this->db->where('emp_no', $emp_no);
    $this->db->where('to_date', '9999-01-01');
    $this->db->update('titles', array('to_date' => $now));
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $this->db->flush_cache();   

    return;
} //END REMOVE EMPLOYEE
```

When I run this code it deleted my records. I don't understand why.

I want it to:
**UPDATE** TABLE **WHERE** CONDITION_1 **AND** CONDITION_2 = B

PS:

```
**$now** is todays date (i.e. 2012-12-25)
**$emp_no** is a unique employee number i.e. 500122
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible way to debug this would be to comment out the `$this->db->delete()`.

Try changing these lines:

```
$this->db->delete('employees', array('emp_no' => $emp_no));
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

To:

```
//$this->db->delete('employees', array('emp_no' => $emp_no));
//$this->db->flush_cache();
```

Then try it and see if your records are still there. If your update was successful and your records are still in the tables, you might have a **Foreign Key** using **Delete Cascade**. Which means if you delete the record from the `employees` table you will also be deleting the records from `dept_emp`, `salaries` and `titles`.

CodeIgniter Active Record Class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

InnoDB Foreign Key: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Check Foreign Keys: [How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column)

Comment: Thanks your spot on. It was these lines which were messing it up. When the foreign key is deleted, it deletes with it all associated records that uses that foreign key. Thank you for your help. :D

Comment: @user1306764 No problem glad I could help, please remember to click the check mark if you feel my answer was an acceptable solution.