# Viewing dependency tree of Foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Well... to be honest, I have absolutely no idea where to even start solving this.

I'd like to view a dependency tree of all my InnoDB tables' Foreign Keys. I want to have a visual representation available.

If it helps, it can be assumed that there are no circular references. I don't know if MySQL even lets you define a circular reference, but anyway...

I just need to know where to look to even find foreign key information, or if there's already a solution out there to do this.

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11302791/1554982?  Looks like you could use the results from this to build up a tree.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to see all the foreign keys is via:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

Coupled with

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

this should provide you the information you are looking for.