# How to know relations between tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, wamp, entity-relationship

I have a database in MySQL created by someone. I don't have any documentation of the database.

How can I know the relationship between the tables?

Is there any query or a procedure to generate a report so that it's easy to find the relations?

I can look into Schema information and manually figure it out, but it would be great if I could generate a relationship report.

Comment: You may use mysql workbench and get ER diagram with all relationships

Comment: possible dupe of... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855065/how-to-find-all-the-relations-between-all-mysql-tables

Comment: Relations are not necessarily available in the database - it is not uncommon in enterprise transactional systems for RI to be stripped out for performance purposes.  Also, some highly customizable systems (PeopleSoft, SAP, Maximo)  maintain RI in the application and have tables to define the relationships.

Comment: This isn't clear. Do you want the FKs that were declared & are recorded in DBMS metadata, or do you mean guessing at ones would or should have been declared by looking at data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The better way as programmatically speaking is gathering data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table as follows:

```
SELECT 
  `TABLE_SCHEMA`,                          -- Foreign key schema
  `TABLE_NAME`,                            -- Foreign key table
  `COLUMN_NAME`,                           -- Foreign key column
  `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA`,               -- Origin key schema
  `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`,                 -- Origin key table
  `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME`                 -- Origin key column
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`  -- Will fail if user don't have privilege
WHERE
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` = SCHEMA()                -- Detect current schema in USE 
  AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` IS NOT NULL; -- Only tables with foreign keys
```

and another one is

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;
```

Comment: I'm using xamp is it will work if write the same query their?

Comment: @Narasimha Maiya i haven't worked on xamp yet.you can try it on xamp .Thanks

Answer (score 20):

You can get an overview in MySql Workbench by doing the steps below:

1. Go to "Database" Menu option.
2. Select the "Reverse Engineer" option.
3. A wizard will be opened and will generate an EER Diagram which shows up

Answer (score 12):

Try out SchemaSpy (http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/):

> SchemaSpy is a Java-based tool (requires Java 5 or higher) that analyzes the metadata of a schema in a database and generates a visual representation of it in a browser-displayable format.

Here is a screenshot of the HTML page of the sample output from http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/ :

[image: Screenshot of the HTML page of the sample output from http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/]

There is also a nice GUI if you do not want to use the command line:
http://schemaspygui.sourceforge.net/

Both tools are open source and in my opinion very lightweight and easy to use. I used them several times when I was in situations that you described: To get an overview of the schema and even some details to dive deeper. (Take a look at the "Anomalies" report.)

---

### Update

Be sure to check out the upcoming version of SchemaSpy at http://schemaspy.org

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the `SELECTs` that use the database?  *That* may be the best source of the relationships.

Answer (score 5):

One more valuable option may be if you just install mysql workbench.( [refers to](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/))
And try "Create EER models from database" .You will surely able to see relations among tables.

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [`information_scheme.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html)

As it is suggested there a quick way to list your FKs (Foreign Key references) using the KEY_COLUMN_USAGE view:

```
SELECT CONCAT( table_name, '.',
column_name, ' -> ',
referenced_table_name, '.',
referenced_column_name ) AS list_of_fks
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = (your schema name here)
AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using phpmyadmin then:

1. Goto the database.
2. Select the table and goto its structure.
3. You'll find relation view at the bottom of your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use Mysql workbench. There is an option for generating ER diagram. If you are using phpmyadmin select any table. There is structure tab from where you can see the table structure. Hopefully, this will help.