# List database table relationships and their type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, relationships

I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically list table relationships in a database, and their type, based on foreign key relationships?

---

Take for example these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    `a_id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk.b.a.b` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `b_c` (
    `b_id` int NOT NULL,
    `c_id` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`,`c_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk.b_c.b.c` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk.b_c.c.b` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

We can get the *foreign key* relationships with this query:

```
SELECT 
    table_name 'table',
    column_name 'column',
    referenced_table_name 'referenced_table',
    referenced_column_name 'referenced_column'
    FROM
        information_schema.key_column_usage
    WHERE
        referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL
        AND table_schema = 'test';

table   column   referenced_table   referenced_column
b       a_id     a                  id
b_c     c_id     c                  id
b_c     b_id     b                  id
```

Now... I *think* the relationship information above *should* be enough to deduce what relationships exists and their types, but I'm not able to translate it into an algorithm... To answer my original question: I know there is a way, but haven't been able to find it.

So, I'm hoping someone more brilliant than I here either knows how one could do this already, or were up for a brain teaser (brain killer, in my case) to solve?

---

Basically, the "answer" should, in this case, be that there are 4 relationships:

- A → B, one-to-many
- B → A, many-to-one
- B → C, many-to-many, through b_c
- C → B, many-to-many, through b_c

I need to do this in PHP, but any sort of understandable algorithm/pseudo code would hopefully help a lot too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855065/how-to-find-all-the-relations-between-all-mysql-tables

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: @Marc-AntoineParent **No**, that's one of the *many* other posts I've found where the answer is (in one variant or another) the SQL I have in my post. My question is about the "next step", i.e. how to "parse" the response *from* that SQL into the relationship type info I list at the end.

Comment: @Svish Alright, sorry for that :) And would you need to represent graphically the relations or only list them?

Comment: @Marc-AntoineParent I just need them in a list, so that I can use the information in my code later. For example, given `b`, I need to know that it has a many-to-one with `a` and a many-to-many with `c` through `b_c`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `one to many` is easy, you already got it. Iterate through this table

```
row table   column   referenced_table   referenced_column
1   b       a_id     a                  id
2   b_c     c_id     c                  id
3   b_c     b_id     b                  id
```

and there you have all the `one to many`

- row 1: A → B, one-to-many
- row 2: C → B_C, one-to-many
- row 3: B → B_C, one-to-many

and all the `many to one` are the reversed of those

- row 1: B → A, many-to-one (reverse of previous)
- row 2: B_C → C, many-to-one (reverse of previous)
- row 3: B_C → B, many-to-one (reverse of previous)

The difficulty would be to find the `many-to-many`, teoretically I think you should use a graph and navigate it to find all `many-to-many` relations, but I can think of a trick you could make with the table you have: group by column table like this

```
SELECT
    table as through,
    GROUP_CONCAT(referenced_table SEPARATOR ',') as tables
FROM (
    SELECT 
        table_name 'table',
        referenced_table_name 'referenced_table',
    FROM
        information_schema.key_column_usage
    WHERE
        referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL
        AND table_schema = 'test';
    ) as yourQuery
GROUP BY table
HAVING count(referenced_table) > 1;
```

You should end with something like this

```
row   through   tables
1     b_c       c,b
```

wich would give to you the name of the through-table in the first column, and the name of the multiple many-to-many tables on the "tables" row (could be 2 or more)

Comment: Neat! What cases would this not cover though? I'm thinking A → C type relations, but don't really need that info on the ready, and not sure what that relationship would be called even... But, any cases not covered in simple two-sided relationships?

Comment: I'm thinking of a case like this `A → B → C ← D`, you might want to know the relation between A and D (many to many through B and C?) and also cyclic cases like `A → A`, or `A → B → A`... etc. I think that all of those could be solved by creating a relations graph and then traversing it. The solution I gave only works for first degree relations, and second degree many-to-many-through

Comment: Aha, right. Think I (hopefully) won't get too complex cases, and think all I need currently are those first-degree and second-degree many-to-many-through. And think I'll be able to get them now if I use your SQL first to get the many-to-many, and then do what you said in the beginning, just filtering out the `through` tables since I don't want them listed. And once I have that, I suppose I could find those "further" relationships by "walking" the data? Guess that's actually maybe sort of doing that graph thing?

Comment: By graph I mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type) by traversing I mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal those are complex algorithms and data structures. I don't know in which context would those "further" relationships could be useful, I just pointed out that it could be a problem for you if you needed them. Also you can "walk" the data, and it would be sort of doing the graph thing, only not the better solution. Also be careful if you are going to "walk" to not get trapped in cycles like `A → B → C → A → B → C → A → ...`

Comment: Ah, exactly. Well, yeah, don't think I need those "further" ones in my case. So... sweet! I'll take this SQL and see if I can *now* build the info I need in my PHP project, which I think I might be able to now actually, so thanks a lot! 

Answer (score 0):

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT * FROM `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`;
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` where constraint_type LIKE 'F%';
SELECT * FROM `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS`;
SELECT * FROM `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN`;
```

That's what I found on 5.6 and MariaDB 10.2.2.

For a many:many table, you may as well go both directions simultaneously.  [*Tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: And, my question is, how would you use that to extract the information I listed at the end of my post?

Comment: My Gut says that you cannot achieve it fully, especially if the FKs are not precisely created.  Also, there are many cases where FKs don't match the "real world"; just look at the number of questions on this forum about FKs.

Comment: OTOH there are a lot of drawing packages that do a reasonably job of painting pictures.

Comment: In this case the FKs are (should be at least) precisely created, and match the real world, because I'm the one creating them  And I don't need a picture, I need the information/data so I can use it in my code.