# Display the database relationship structure

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am following a SQL tutorial, it states

> Database administrators often use relationship diagrams to help demonstrate how database tables are connected.
>   [image]

However,I tried every corner of mysql workbench but failed to find such a well-organized diagram.

How could I see the database structure as the diagram shows?

Comment: you can use mysql workbench to draw the diagram https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-creating-eer-diagram.html

Comment: At least in older versions the mysql-workbench offered to "reverse engineer" an existing database. That did work a bit, spit out such a diagram, but nothing you could really use in a non-trivial scenario. The issue is that you need to have intelligence to understand a database. So typically it makes more sense to draw a diagram yourself. Actually it should be part of the documentation the developers write.

Comment: Is it helpful? you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855065/how-to-find-all-the-relations-between-all-mysql-tables

Comment: ty, I am upgrading mysql workbench, using 5.7 now @pwxcoo

Comment: I found "reverse engineer" in version 6.3 @arkascha thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Generate Database Diagram MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql)

Comment: You may need to install additional software. You can try SchemaCrawler or SchemaSpy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't find [the modeling part of MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-documenting-sakila.html) yet. Walk through the tutorials to reverse engineer a schema and create an EER model from it.

[image]

You can customize colors and figure sizes + positions, organize a diagram with layers for better overview and change the notation (crow food etc.). Search for modeling with MySQL Workbench for more tips.

Answer (score -2):

I learned long time ago database structure. But as I see on your picture, the diagram shows columns of tables and the relations between them.
1:N - means from the other table allowed to reference more than 1 records
1:1 - means from the other table allowed to reference only one record.
Example: relation between customers and orders. 
The orders can have many customers_id and same customers as well. Because one customer can send more order.
You can find customer_id in order table too.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That does not at all answer the OP's question. He/she asked where such a diagram can be found, not what it expresses.