# How to get relationship between tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

Hi I am creating a ER diagram for my organization. How can i get the relationship between the tables in snowflake

Thanks

Comment: You have to understand what the data represents.  In a well designed database, naming conventions, foreign key constraints, and documentation can all help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reverse engineer a current Snowflake database, you may have trouble.  Foreign key constraints can be included in the table definition, however they are not enforced.  If your developers included the constraints when they defined the tables, you can get the relationship from the table definitions. It is a good practice to include the constraints as many third party tools use them.

Answer (score 0):

Do a deep study of all the relations of tables.
And try writing all the conditions on which two or more tables are connected

```
    SELECT
    `TABLE_NAME',
    `COLUMN_NAME`,
     FROM `YOUR_DATABASE`
     WHERE 'PUT YOUR CONDITIONS '
```

This should solve your question
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855065/how-to-find-all-the-relations-between-all-mysql-tables#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20Reverse%20Engineer%20option,generate%20a%20diagram%20with%20relationships.)