# How do I generate ADD FOREIGN KEY statements for a group of tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37.  Given a group of tables, (table_a, table_b, ..., table_n), how do I write an SQL statement (or procedure) that will generate the SQL that produces all the foreign keys that these tables link to?  Note that although I can run a mysqldump that will produce "CREATE TABLE" statements with "CONSTRAINT" clauses, I want ONLY the statmeents that will add the foreign keys, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE table_a ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES table_x(P_Id)
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Are the foreign key constraints already in the schema? If so, you can get the information from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table.

Comment: Yes, the foreign key constraints are already in teh schema.  I'm still a little hazy, though on how I'd use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE to generate the correct "ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT" statements.  Do you have any examples?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/201678/1491895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name,
              ' ADD FOREIGN KEY (', constraint_name, ')',
              ' REFERENCES ', referenced_table_name,
              '(', referenced_column_name, ');') AS alter_cmd
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is tremendous.  Oen other thing ... if there wsa an "ON DELETE CASCADE" part of the constraint, how do I find that?

Comment: It's in the `information_schema.referential_constraints` table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/referential-constraints-table.html

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. I'm unable to edit, there is a 6 character minimum change