# How do you check if a table or a column has been used as a Foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table called as customers and it has columns like id, name, address

Now I know for a fact that the id from customers is used as a Foreign key in a few tables but I dont know the whole list.

Is there a way I can find out all the tables that are dependent on records in customers table before I delete a particular record i.e. basically find out if my customers table or column from customers table has been used as a Foreign key in another table

Comment: A quick google search has shown me this stack over flow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column -- perhaps it could help.

Comment: @Landen Thanks.. thats exactly what I was looking for.