# MySQL get foreign keys from a view table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a view table (let's call it `view_table`) composed of two tables (let's call them `table_1` & `table_2`).  Let's assume that `table_1` has a foreign key on the field `fk_field` that references the table `fk_table`.

Is there anyway to directly query `view_table` in order get the reference table `fk_table` for the field `fk_field`?

I'm doing this from PHP so I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

1. Parse the `VIEW_DEFINITION` field from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` in order to get a list of tables that constitute `view_table` (e.g. `table_1` & `table_2`)
2. For each of those tables, use the [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201678) to get `fk_table`

Is there a better (i.e. simpler) approach?

**EDIT**

The view definition in this case, the field `Container` is a foreign key which references a table named `Containers`:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `LIMS_dev`.`DerivativeView` AS
    SELECT 
        `a`.`Derivative` AS `Derivative`,
        `a`.`Container` AS `Container`,
        `a`.`DerivativeTypeID` AS `DerivativeTypeID`,
        `a`.`StorageFormatID` AS `StorageFormatID`,
        `a`.`SourceSample` AS `SourceSample`,
        `a`.`Parent` AS `Parent`,
        `a`.`Date` AS `DerivativeDate`,
        `a`.`Active` AS `SampleActive`,
        `a`.`User` AS `User`,
        `a`.`Notes` AS `Notes`,
        `b`.`Shelf` AS `Shelf`,
        `b`.`Rack` AS `Rack`,
        `b`.`FreezerID` AS `FreezerID`,
        `b`.`Active` AS `BoxActive`,
        `b`.`Date` AS `ContainerDate`
    FROM
        (`LIMS_dev`.`Derivatives` `a`
        LEFT JOIN `LIMS_dev`.`Containers` `b` ON ((`a`.`Container` = `b`.`Container`)))
```

Comment: show your view_table code ...

Comment: You can parse the CREATE statements, and extract what you need from that, [maybe use this as a starting point](https://github.com/EVODelavega/mysql-diff)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a simple `JOIN`? `SELECT * FROM view_table INNER JOIN fk_table USING (fk_field);`?

Comment: perhaps I could, but what about the hoops needed just to find fk_table and the field fk_field?  I can't assume to know those beforehand.

Comment: @constantino: If you process the create table statement, you'll know the fk table and field, then you can query the DB for the create statement of that table, and work your way up to the point where you what all the tables you're interested in look like, what fields they contain and all that (that's what that mysql-diff thingy I linked to does anyway)

Comment: yep that's what I ended up doing: