# MySQL Drop column along with all it's foreign key constraints (PHP PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to drop a column of a table via PHP (PDO). However there is a foreign key constraint on the column in question.

So I would like to drop the constraints placed on this column along with column.

```
DBCon::getCon()->query('ALTER TABLE `module_column` DROP COLUMN `module_id`');
```

How do I drop the foreign key constraints along with the column?

Comment: You need to drop the constraints first. AFAIK there's no "drop the column with all its constraints" command

Comment: Is there atleast a way to get the constraint names from a specific column? as in a `get all constraints for module_column.module_id` command.

Comment: Yes, see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201678/4681654)