# MySQL - How to list all tables that have a foreign key referring to my table's primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MYSQL database I want to find out all the tables in the current db that have my selected table's primary key as their foreign key, in other words they are referring to my table.

Comment: Already asked and answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the last answer was almost correct. just change the table from "key_column" to "key_column_usage.

Cheers

Nikao

Answer (score 3):

You can just do something like this:

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT *
FROM
  key_column_usage
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
  AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'table_id'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Replace the `table_name` and `table_id` with the your table name and column name.

Comment: It gives me a error code 1064, there is something wrong with my sql syntax