# Query a table's relation in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a mysql query which returns the relationship between tables?

I tried `show full columns from <atable>;` but it only returns meta data on columns excluding `foreign keys`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable` should show the full create statement, which should include foreign key defintions.  Beyond this, if you want to see a full graph of table relationships, you would probably have to use a tool outside of MySQL which specializes in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

All of your keys are in the  [KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html) table and the type of constraint they are (primary key, Foriegn Key) should be in [TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-constraints-table.html)  table

Comment: I am using mysql 5.6 and could not locate any table with name `TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`.

Comment: Both of these tables are available in that version as well they are in the Information_schema. This article on stack exchange will demonstrate how to use it. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93919/mysql-list-databases-with-tables