# How to import a table that was deleted with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have deleted a table from my server called 'companies' that has foreign keys and also has relationships with other tables. Now I'm trying to import the table again with a backup I download, but it throws an error of incorrectly formed foreign keys

I have tried to create just the table with 2 charts a name and an id, but it's not working it also throws the error of Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`company_email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`company_phone` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`logo` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`login_background` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`website` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`currency_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
`package_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
`package_type` enum('monthly','annual') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL 
 DEFAULT 'monthly',
 `timezone` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Asia/Kolkata',
 `date_format` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'd-m-Y',
 `time_format` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'h:i a',
 `locale` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
 `latitude` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 26.91243360,
 `longitude` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 75.78727090,
 `leaves_start_from` enum('joining_date','year_start') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'joining_date',
 `active_theme` enum('default','custom') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
 `status` enum('active','inactive','license_expired') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
 `last_updated_by` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `stripe_id` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `card_brand` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `card_last_four` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `trial_ends_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `licence_expire_on` date DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Error Message:**

```
(Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is to get all foreign keys of "Comapanies" table using this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column).

Then drop all foreign keys

```
ALTER TABLE `companies`
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`;
```

Then execute your create table statement