# MySQL: How to determine foreign key relationships programmatically?

Tags: sql, mysql, c, foreign-keys

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85978/query-a-tables-foreign-key-relationships) but for MySQL....

How can I programmatically determine foreign key references in MySQL (assuming InnoDB)?  I can almost get them with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'MyTableName';
```

...but alas, the comment column which seems to contain some of this info gets truncated so I can't rely on it.  There must be some other way...

I'd be happy with a C API call, a SQL statement, anything--I just need something that consistently works.

Note:  I've also considered parsing the results of a "SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTableName" statement, but I'm really hoping there's something simpler.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two tables you can query to get this information: [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) and [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/key-column-usage-table.html).

Here's a query from the comments on the latter page linked above, which demonstrates how to get the info you seek.

```
SELECT CONCAT( table_name, '.', column_name, ' -> ', 
  referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name ) AS list_of_fks 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage 
WHERE referenced_table_schema = 'test' 
  AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY table_name, column_name;
```

Use your schema name instead of '`test`' above.

Comment: A pretty slow query.... `/* 0 rows affected, 22 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 2,996 sec. */`

Comment: @V-Light, you have another solution?

Answer (score 7):

Here you have a little improvement over the @bill solution:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AS db,
       CONCAT (
           TABLE_NAME,
           '.',
           COLUMN_NAME,
           ' -> ',
           REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
           '.',
           REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
       ) AS relationship 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
         TABLE_NAME,
         COLUMN_NAME;
```

In this case I was filtering by relationships with the "your_table_name" fields and seeing from which database the relationship comes.

Answer (score 2):

Try `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`

Comment: I don't seem to have that table, though I do have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS which has most (but not quite all) the info I need.  Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

based on Bill Karwin answered, I used this solution to get all the info I needed, included on_delete and on_update rules:

```
SELECT kcu.referenced_table_schema, kcu.constraint_name, kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name, kcu.referenced_table_name, kcu.referenced_column_name, 
       rc.update_rule, rc.delete_rule 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage kcu
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
WHERE kcu.referenced_table_schema = 'db_name' 
AND kcu.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'table_schema';
```

Comment: While your query seem to work, please provide the community with a little statement on how it works.