# How can I get the foreign keys of a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, parent-child

I am creating a class which, takes a table from a database, and displays it to a web-page, with as much functionality as possible. One of the things I would like to support, would be having the class detect which columns in the table have a foreign key constraint on them, so that it can then go to those tables, get all of their values and use them in a select-box which is called when you edit those fields, to avoid someone violating foreign key constraints,

The main problem is discovering which fields have a foreign key constraint on them, and which tables they are pointing to. Does anyone know how to do this???

Thanks,

Lemiant

Comment: I asked this same question a while back--see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273794/mysql-how-to-determine-foreign-key-relationships-programmatically

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple way to get foreign keys for given table:

```
SELECT
    `column_name`, 
    `referenced_table_schema` AS foreign_db, 
    `referenced_table_name` AS foreign_table, 
    `referenced_column_name`  AS foreign_column 
FROM
    `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE
    `constraint_schema` = SCHEMA()
AND
    `table_name` = 'your-table-name-here'
AND
    `referenced_column_name` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    `column_name`;
```

Comment: `table_schema = DATABASE()` for the currently connected DB.

Comment: I don't get the `constraint_schema` = SCHEMA() part, constraint_schema is just the name of the constraint, am I right?
It should be table_schema = 'your-db-name-here' instead

Answer (score 5):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains details of the full schema of all other databases, including constraints:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

You can also run a SHOW CREATE TABLE query to get the SQL to create a table, including its constraints.

Comment: To add, FK info is only available on tables that use InnoDB storage. From the manual:`For storage engines other than InnoDB, MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN KEY syntax in CREATE TABLE statements, but does not use or store it.`

Comment: thanks, `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` shows all needed informations!

Answer (score 0):

Much can be retrieved from MySQL's `information_schema`, foreign keys included, as pointed out by dev-null-dweller.

#### 1

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
         WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' AND table_name='mytable';
```

Instead of dbname use the function `SCHEMA()` to set the name of the database in `USE`.

---

#### 2

As pointed out by Dan Grossman, the command

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `yourtablename`
```

can be used basically get an SQL dump of the create table statement.

---

#### ~3

MySQL provides a SHOW KEYS command. As such you could theoretically get the FK if you know a lower cardinality threshold and have few other keys in the table.

```
SHOW KEYS FROM `address` WHERE Non_unique AND CARDINALITY > 10000
```

As the key's cardinality changes each time the internal database is changed, this is rather theoretical. See the cardinality change for instance with running `ANALYZE TABLE`.

---

~4

It is useful to stick to a naming schema, such as `foreigntablename_foreignfieldname`. For example the field `user_id` in a table `billing`. Several ORMs of big Web Content Frameworks use this schema.

Answer (score 0):

based on Bill Karwin answer in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273794/mysql-how-to-determine-foreign-key-relationships-programmatically), I used this solution to get all the info I needed, included on_delete and on_update rules:

```
SELECT kcu.referenced_table_schema, kcu.constraint_name, kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name, kcu.referenced_table_name, kcu.referenced_column_name, 
   rc.update_rule, rc.delete_rule 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage kcu
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
WHERE kcu.referenced_table_schema = 'db_name' 
AND kcu.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name
```