# Check SQL constraint value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to check a specific value of an existing constraint?

For example I want to check if a `FOREIGN KEY` Constraint is `ON DELETE SET NULL` or `ON DELETE NO ACTION`.

I only found solutions if a constraint is existing at all, but not for a specific value.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `mysql` **and** `postgres`?

Comment: Because it's an application that should run with these two databases.

Answer (score 1):

As dev-null-dweller suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159998/how-can-i-get-the-foreign-keys-of-a-table-in-mysql/4160215#4160215):

> Simple way to get foreign keys for given table:
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     `column_name`, 
>     `referenced_table_schema` AS foreign_db, 
>     `referenced_table_name` AS foreign_table, 
>     `referenced_column_name`  AS foreign_column 
> FROM
>     `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
> WHERE
>     `constraint_schema` = SCHEMA()
> AND
>     `table_name` = 'your-table-name-here'
> AND
>     `referenced_column_name` IS NOT NULL
> ORDER BY
>     `column_name`;
> ```

Or another way, [suggested by Lo Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159998/how-can-i-get-the-foreign-keys-of-a-table-in-mysql/18705476#18705476), is:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
         WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' AND table_name='mytable';
```

Comment: @MarcelBalzer: no that won't work on Postgres due to the non-standard backticks, the non-existing `schema()` function and the fact that the `information_schema` tables are quite different between the two DBMS.

Comment: OK, but this works in Mysql and yours in PGSQL. Thanks both ;)

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres this would be something like:

```
select tc.table_schema||'.'||tc.table_name as referencing_table, 
       ctu.table_schema||'.'||ctu.table_name as referenced_table_name,
       rc.update_rule, 
       rc.delete_rule
from information_schema.table_constraints tc
  join information_schema.referential_constraints rc 
    on tc.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog 
   and tc.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema 
   and tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
  join information_schema.constraint_table_usage ctu 
    on ctu.constraint_catalog = rc.unique_constraint_catalog
   and ctu.constraint_schema = rc.unique_constraint_schema
   and ctu.constraint_name = rc.unique_constraint_name
where tc.table_name = 'foobar'
  and tc.table_schema = 'public'
  and tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

But that won't work on MySQL