# How does phpmyadmin get foreign key value?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This not phpmyadmin feature enhancement for internal relationships. I am using InnoDB.

I want to know how to Phpmyadmin create select value from foreign key.

This is example :

[image]

I have used a foreign key in PhpMyAdmin, I am very curious, how PhpMyAdmin can detect the options that have been used for the foreign key. I have some experiments with selecting data in INFORMATION_SCHEMA and it took a long time to load it, is there any way to get the foreign key value only with MySQL query?

Comment: Please add the code you used to access the 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' schema to get the foreign key. maybe interesting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159998/how-can-i-get-the-foreign-keys-of-a-table-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks, my question is duplicated, that ismy answer, @RyanVincent