# How to get relations between table and distinguish one to one and one to many?

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like to ask you how to get relations between tables ? I don't have access to script that creates all tables in database. So is it any SQL query that let me get relations and type of relations ? Is it possible or not, i have access to database but not to creating script ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, i mean  foreign keys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column#201678

Comment: I am checking, but it doesn't return type of relations, only display relations exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA KEY_COLUMN_USAGE Table.

It takes some time to run, but gives you all foreign keys in your database

```
SELECT 
     `TABLE_NAME`,
     `COLUMN_NAME`,
     `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`,
     `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM
     `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` 
WHERE `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` = 'your_database_name' 
     AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA` IS NOT NULL 
     AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` IS NOT NULL 
     AND `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ;
```

> "The KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table describes which key columns have constraints."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't return me one to one or one to many. Is it possible to achive that

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103542/how-to-determine-programmatically-mysql-relationship-type-11-1n-nm-betwee)

Comment: This doesn't work, it shows me that every relation is one to one