# How do you get the relationship type as in one-many with MySQL and T-SQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have seen several posts on how to get foreign key references but not the actual relationship type like what is shown in MySQL's workbench ER diagram.

Currently I am using below sql to get references

```
SELECT 
  `TABLE_SCHEMA`,                          -- Foreign key schema
  `TABLE_NAME`,                            -- Foreign key table
  `COLUMN_NAME`,                           -- Foreign key column
  `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA`,               -- Origin key schema
  `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`,                 -- Origin key table
  `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME`                 -- Origin key column
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`  -- Will fail if user don't have privilege
WHERE
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` = SCHEMA()                -- Detect current schema in USE 
  AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` = 'orders'; -- Only tables with foreign keys
```

What sql do I need to use to let me know if it is a 1:M, M:1, 1:1,

I have read [How to determine cardinality of foreign key using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618285/how-to-determine-cardinality-of-foreign-key-using-mysql) which hints at how to find this info.

Does any have an example sql statment to get the relationship type?

Comment: For MySQL check: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273794/mysql-how-to-determine-foreign-key-relationships-programmatically) For SQL Server check: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: This does not give tell you if it is 1:M M:M

Comment: An M:M relationship cannot be modeled with a single FK. You need an additional table, so you will have two FK-s for one M:M relationship. At best, you can describe a FK as 1:M or 1:1, based on the existance of an unique index with the same columns in the same table as the FK (not in the referenced table, where it must always exist).