# SQL Server 2000 - Query a Table’s Foreign Key relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000, foreign-keys

*Nearly identical to [Query a Table's Foreign Key relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85978/query-a-tables-foreign-key-relationships), but for SQL Server 2000*

For a given table 'foo', I need a query to generate a set of tables that have foreign keys that point to foo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT o2.name
FROM sysobjects o
INNER JOIN sysforeignkeys fk on o.id = fk.rkeyid
INNER JOIN sysobjects o2 on fk.fkeyid = o2.id
WHERE o.name = 'foo'
```

Comment: If you want the column names too (thanks alex): 

SELECT  
      o2.name, 
      col_name(rkeyid, rkey) as referenced_column_name  
 FROM sysobjects o 
 INNER JOIN sysforeignkeys fk on o.id = fk.rkeyid 
 INNER JOIN sysobjects o2 on fk.fkeyid = o2.id 
 WHERE o.name = 'ATE_Question'

Answer (score 3):

Try this T-SQL:

```
select col_name(fkeyid, fkey) as column_name, object_name(rkeyid) as referenced_table_name, col_name(rkeyid, rkey) as referenced_column_name from sysforeignkeys where object_name(fkeyid) = 'tableNameHere' order by constid
```

I've rewritten the query slightly to give you all of the other tables that rely on a particular table:

```
select object_name(fkeyid),
col_name(fkeyid, fkey) as column_name,
col_name(rkeyid, rkey) as referenced_column_name
from sysforeignkeys
where object_name(rkeyid) = 'tableNameHere'
order by constid
```

Comment: with all due respect, who the hell voted me down here? Out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Parents and children

```
/* this will find out all of the foreign key references for a table*/

DECLARE @tableName varchar(128)
SET @tableName = 'tCounter'

SELECT   
    pt.[name] AS 'parentTable',  
    ct.[name] AS 'childTable',  
    fk.[name] AS 'fkName', 
*   
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk        
    INNER JOIN sys.tables pt              
        ON pt.object_ID = fk.parent_object_id        
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ct              
        ON ct.object_ID = fk.referenced_object_id   
WHERE pt.name = @tableName      
    OR ct.name = @tableName   
ORDER BY pt.name, ct.name
```

Comment: This is exactly what was asked for and then some.

Comment: I ran it and there was zero output.  Should have been a comment regarding this before marking it down.

Comment: If you ran it an there was no output then there are no foreign keys defined.

Answer (score 1):

Start here

```
    SELECT cons.TABLE_NAME
    , cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_NAME
    , cols.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS cons
LEFT join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cols
ON cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cols.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'foreign KEY'
ORDER BY cons.TABLE_NAME
    , cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , cols.COLUMN_NAME
```

[edit] formatting is all messed up

[edit2] no longer

Comment: close... Credit for a query that works.  

For a given table 'foo', I need a query to generate a set of tables that have foreign keys that point to foo.