# SQL 2000: T-SQL to get foreign key relationships for a table

Tags: sql-server-2000, foreign-key-relationship

Similar but NOT IDENTICAL to [SQL Server 2000 - Query a Table’s Foreign Key relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444523/sql-server-2000-query-a-tables-foreign-key-relationships)

I need a T-SQL statement that will work SQL 2000 that given a table name, will return the foreign key relationships for that table e.g.

Table MyFristTable has a foreign key to MySecondTable, where MyFirstTable.ColA must be in MySecondTable.ColB. I'd be delighted, if the sql statement (or stored proc) is ran for MyFirstTable and returned a result set on the lines of

```
Column | FK_Table      | FK_COLUMN
----------------------------------
ColA   | MySecondTable | ColB
```

**NB**: I have samples for SQL 2005 that won't work because they rely on sys.foreign_key_columns

I'd rather not have to parse out the results of the sp_help statement.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname

SET @tableName = '' -- Your table name goes here

SELECT
    c.name
    , target.name
    , targetc.name
FROM
    -- source table
    sysobjects t
    -- source column
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c ON t.id = c.id
    -- general constraint
    INNER JOIN sysconstraints co ON t.id = co.id AND co.colid = c.colid
    -- foreign key constraint
    INNER JOIN sysforeignkeys fk ON co.constid = fk.constid
    -- target table
    INNER JOIN sysobjects target ON fk.rkeyid = target.id
    -- target column
    INNER JOIN syscolumns targetc ON fk.rkey = targetc.colid AND fk.rkeyid = targetc.id
WHERE
    t.name = @tableName
```

**NOTE** I have I think used only those system views available in SQL 2000 (ie the sysXXX ones rather than the SQL 2005 sys.XXX ones) but I have only actually tested this in a SQL 2005 environemnt.

Comment: This does not include relationships with keys composed of multiple columns

Answer (score 13):

I had to do this exact thing for a query, and I found this stored procedure, after trying a version much like the sys table one:

```
exec sp_fkeys @fktable_name = 'foo'
```

It looks like this is available in [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933402%28SQL.80%29.aspx).
Also, I found that in a few cases there were minor differences between this stored proc and the queries here. I'm guessing sp_fkeys is the canonical version.

Comment: Wow, I really I can't understand why this wasn't up-voted more!  Brilliant!  I would so rather remember to exec one fairly well-named stored proc than to bother with typing in a huge query to get this.

Comment: @Ogre: I was a few months late. :)

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, it helped me, and hopefully will help future answer-seekers.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in google... so if this work is not my merit. Hope it help

```
 SELECT 
        FK_Table  = FK.TABLE_NAME, 
        FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME, 
        PK_Table  = PK.TABLE_NAME, 
        PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME, 
        Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C 
        INNER JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK 
            ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        INNER JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK 
            ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        INNER JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU 
            ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        INNER JOIN 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM 
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1 
                INNER JOIN 
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
                WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
        ) PT 
        ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME 

    WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME='something'    -- the table for you are asking
```

Comment: FK constraints might not reference the PK on the other table: any unique constraint may be used.

Comment: +1  : My answer was not complete, this is, so I deleted mine,

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this once, so I just looked at the source code of the system stored procedure and copied what I needed into my own procedure and made it work as I needed.

You might look at sp_helpconstraint's source code...

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to look at the source of the system proc, that would never have occurred to me. Thanks mate.