# Please tell me how to get primary key name in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, primary-key

I need a primary key name and primary key column name of a table please tell me what query should I write..

Comment: I assume you're working on a generic database utility of some sorts; otherwise you should **know** this information already. I would would write a query against the system tables `sysobects` and `sysindexes` to get this information. However, I am aware that MS have provided useful meta-data views in later versions of SQL Server; and you'd be better off using those.

Comment: Your question reads as if you expect a primary key to only refer to one column - this is far from always true. And of course, not every table has a PK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @tableName as nvarchar(100)
set @tableName = 'table'

select i.name, c.name 
from sys.index_columns ic 
    join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id=i.index_id
    join sys.columns c on c.column_id=ic.column_id
where 
    i.[object_id] = object_id(@tableName) and 
    ic.[object_id] = object_id(@tableName) and 
    c.[object_id] = object_id(@tableName) and
    is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: Why only 100? Sysname can be 128.

Comment: No reason, really. I just used an even number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that uses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views

```
SELECT 
    cu.Table_Catalog,
    cu.Table_Schema,
    cu.table_name,
    cu.Constraint_name  ,
    cu.column_name

FROM 
    sys.indexes si
    inner join  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
    on si.name = cu.constraint_name
WHERE 
    is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: +1 This is preferable to the database-specific sys tables. (@soslo: how slow can it be??? :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're looking for, but you can play around with it:

[SQL 2000: T-SQL to get foreign key relationships for a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026673/sql-2000-t-sql-to-get-foreign-key-relationships-for-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Just a performance note - the select using sys tables is a couple orders of magnitude faster than the select that uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA views