# How to see the table relationships in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, table-relationships

I had an Access database.

Now I have created a connection with this Access DB and copied it to ORACLE.

I hope the keys and constraints must be recreated in Oracle.

**I couldn't find out how to create the relationships between the tables.**

**And also visualizing them.**

Comment: The answer for this question is here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85978/query-a-tables-foreign-key-relationships

Answer (score 7):

First of all your db keys and constraints should be maintained if you have completed migration from Access DB to Oracle successfully.

Having said that, there are products for Oracle database that will help you to visualize table relationships. There is a product called "PL/SQL Developer by Allround Automations", which we use as company, that includes this in their GUI interface - they have both "foreign keys" and "foreign key references" branches in their navigation tree for a table node (The product is not free though..). You can check [here](http://www.allroundautomations.com/bodyplsqldev7.html) for detailed information about the 'Diagram Window' feature of PL/SQL Developer.

Secondly Oracle's SQL Developer (which is free) has a feature called 'Data Modeling' for visual representation of displaying the Relational. Check [here](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/395473.png) for Oracle SQL Developer's Data Modeling.

Furthermore if you want to find out the tables that have references to a specific table you can also use the following query:

```
select table_name from user_constraints
where r_constraint_name in
  (select constraint_name 
     from user_constraints
     where constraint_type in ('P','U')
     and table_name = upper('&tableOfInterest')
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).  It is a free tool from Oracle that allows you to view and modify your database within a GUI.  It also has a data modeler built in.  It is also free (you just need to have Oracle first)